# If-else statements in function using array(s). Error: The truth value with more than one element is ambigious

Tags: arrays, if-statement, plot

I have this code which calculates the energy produced in fusion processes (PP-chain and CNO cycle), as well as the relative energy, which i want to plot against a temperature interval. But when i run the program i get the error: 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous'.

This is a problem with the if-statements in the code, i figured, as T is an array not a scalar. How do I solve this, i.e. implement the if conditions such that the code works and i get a ,correct, plot.

```
def pp_chain(rho,T):
    
    
    N_A = 6.022e23      #Avogadro's constant inverse
    mu =  1.6605e-27     #Units of [kg]
    Joule = 1.60217e-13        #Converting Mev to Joule (SI)


    #Mass fraction of each nuclei
    X= 0.7
    Y = 0.29
    Y3He = 1e-10
    Z7Li = 1e-7
    Z7Be = 1e-7
    Z14N = 1e-11

    #Q-values of the different reactions, i.e. energy released
    Q_pp = 1.177*Joule
    Q_pd = 5.494*Joule
    Q_33 = 12.86*Joule
    Q_34 = 1.586*Joule
    Q_e7 = 0.049*Joule
    Q_17s = 17.346*Joule
    Q_17 = 0.137*Joule
    Q_8 = (8.367+2.995)*Joule
    Q_CNO = (1.944 + 1.513+7.551 + 7.297+1.757 + 4.966)*Joule

    
    #number density of each nuclei (in each reaction)
    n_p = ((rho*X)/(mu))
    nHe3 = (rho*Y3He)/(3*mu)
    nHe4 = ((rho*Y)/(4*mu))
    ne7 = (rho*Z7Be/(7*mu))
    n17s = ((rho*Z7Li)/(7*mu))
    nCNO = ((rho*Z14N)/(14*mu))
    n_e = n_p+ 2*nHe4 + 2*nHe3 + 4*ne7 + 3*n17s + 7*nCNO
    
    
    T9 = T/(1e9)
    
    #The  reaction rates (per unit mass)for each reaction
    #in reaction lambda_e7. 


    lambda_pp = ((4.01e-15*T9**(-2/3)*np.exp(-3.380*T9**(-1/3))*(1+0.123*T9**(1/3)+1.09*T9**(2/3)+0.938*T9))/N_A)*0.000001

    lambda_33 = ((6.04e10*T9**(-2/3)*np.exp(-12.276*T9**(-1/3))*(1+0.034*T9**(1/3)-0.522*T9**(2/3)-0.124*T9+0.353*T9**(4/3)+0.213*T9**(5/3)))/N_A)*0.000001


    Ts = T9/(1+4.95e-2*T9)
    lambda_34 = ((5.61e6*Ts**(5/6)*T9**(-3/2)*np.exp(-12.826*Ts**(-1/3)))/N_A)*0.000001
    

    if T<1e6:

      return lambda_e7 =((1.57e-7/n_e)/N_A)*0.000001
    else:
       return lambda_e7 = ((1.34e-10*T9**(-1/2)*(1-0.537*T9**(1/3)+3.86*T9**(2/3)+0.0027*T9**(-1)*np.exp(2.515e-3*T9**(-1))))/N_A)*0.000001
    
    
    Tss = T9/(1+0.759*T9)
    lambda_71Li = ((1.096e9*T9**(-2/3)*np.exp(-8.472*T9**(-1/3))-4.830e8*Tss*(5/6)*T9**(-3/2)*np.exp(-8.472*Tss**(-1/3))+1.06e10*T9**(-3/2)*np.exp(-30.442*T9**(-1)))/N_A)*0.000001


    lambda_71Be = ((3.11e5*T9**(-2/3)*np.exp(-10.262*T9**(-1/3))+2.53e3*T9**(-3/2)*np.exp(-7.306*T9**(-1)))/N_A)*0.000001


    lambda_CNO = ((4.90e7*T9**(-2/3)*np.exp(-15.228*T9**(-1/3)-0.092*T9**2)*(1+0.027*T9**(1/3)-0.778*T9**(2/3)-0.149*T9+0.261*T9**(4/3)+0.127*T9**(5/3)) + 2.37e3*T9**(-3/2)*np.exp(-3.011*T9**(-1))+2.19e4*np.exp(-12.53*T9**(-1)))/N_A)*0.000001
    

    ##The  reaction rates for each reaction
    
    
    r_pp = (n_p*n_p)/(2*rho)*lambda_pp
    r_33 = (nHe3*nHe3)/(2*rho)*lambda_33
    r_34 = ((nHe4*nHe3)/rho)*lambda_34
    r_e7 = ((ne7*n_e)/rho)*lambda_e7
    r_71Li = ((n17s*n_p)/rho)*lambda_71Li
    r_71Be = ((ne7*n_p)/rho)*lambda_71Be
    r_CNO = ((nCNO*n_p)/rho)*lambda_CNO
    
    
    if r_pp<(r_34+2*r_33):
      R1 = r_pp/(2*r_33+r_34)
      r_33 = r_33*R1
      r_34 = r_34*R1 
    

    
    if (r_34<(r_e7 + r_71Be)):
        R2 = r_34/(r_e7 + r_71Be)
        r_e7 = r_e7*R2
        r_71Be = r_71Be*R2
    
    
     
    if (r_e7 <(r_71Li)):
        R3 = r_e7/(r_71Li)
        r_71Li = R3*r_71Li
     
    
    #Energy generation per unit mass from PP1,PP2, PP3 and CNO, found by multiplying energy released
    #with reaction rates of the reactions that occur in each branch
    
    PP0 = r_pp*(Q_pp + Q_pd)
    PP1 = r_33*Q33+ r_33*2*(Qpp+Qpd)
    PP2 = r_34*Q_34 + r_e7*Q_e7 + r_71Li*Q_17s + r_34*(Qpp+Qpd)
    PP3 = r_34*Q_34 + r_71Be*Q_17 + r_34*(Qpp + Qpd)
    CNO = r_CNO*Q_CNO
    epsilon = PP1+PP2+PP3+CNO
    
    #Relative energy
    E_rel1= PP1/epsilon
    E_rel2= PP2/epsilon
    E_rel3 = PP3/epsilon
    E_rel4 = CNO/epsilon
   

     return  E_rel1, E_rel2,E_rel3,E_rel4

#Defining the different temperatures used in function
rho = 1.62e5
T =  np.arange(1e4,1e9,100)

#Calling the function for energy generated in eanch branch and printing the result
energy_prod = pp_chain(rho, T)



rel_energy1 = energy_prod[0]
rel_energy2 = energy_prod[1]
rel_energy3 = energy_prod[2]
rel_energy4 = energy_prod[3]

plt.plot(T, rel_energy1,label = 'PP1')
plt.plot(T, rel_energy2,label = 'PP2')
plt.plot(T, rel_energy3,label = 'PP3')
plt.plot(T, rel_energy4,label = 'CNO')
plt.title('Energy prooduced in each PP chain/CNO cycle')
plt.ylabel('Relative Energy [J]')
plt.xlabel('T [K]')
plt.xscale('log')
#plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I did attempt to use np.all/np.any which it said i should use in the error. Doing this i did get a plot, except two of the relative energies (CNO and PP3?) did not behave as expected, thus i concluded that i shouldn't use that.  After this i tried with np.where, though i was unsure how to implement it with the if statements for r_pp and r_34 as the conditions return two values if condition is true.

Comment: `T<1e6:` is likely to  be the problem.  Always try searching for the error message first. [Google provides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)